# What determines SPECIAL inheritance in children?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In Fallout Shelter you're able to make babies when you assign a male and female dweller to a residential area. When the babies are born, what determines the SPECIAL stats? It seems to be somewhat influenced by their parents, but there seem to be other variables. I want to breed children with high SPECIAL scores.

Comment: Mh, I'm not quite sure. I have to parents with high S stats. The child was born and have a quite low S value and a middle P value. Not sure if there is any influence or just random.

Comment: At this point I'm pretty sure it's totally random.  I have mated most of my women with my "Stud", a high level and high attribute dweller.  I have also mated a few "normal" couples together, people of low level and normal attributes.  I have yet to notice any appreciable difference in the SPECIAL attributes of any of the kids.  They all seem to come out with the normal 1 - 2 in most attributes with the occasional 3.  Never anything more, sadly.  :(

Comment: Have a look at this question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/237881/how-do-i-make-sure-my-child-is-smart

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The highest average stat between the two parents determines what the child's highest stat will be.  However, it only decides what the highest stat will be, not the value of that stat.

Comment: +1, this seems to correlate my own experience. I've yet to record a child who was born with more than a 3 special score, so it's possible that is the max.

Comment: That's a shame, I had imageined myself doing a long term Eugenics program to create the new super species of dwellers. :)

Comment: Do you have a source for this? It directly contradicts another answer.

Answer (score 0):

The *SPECIAL* stats are *randomly* generated for each dweller. You can upgrade their *SPECIAL* stats though with these rooms:

- Classroom - Intelligence
- Armory - Perception
- Weight Room - Strength
- Athletics Room - Agility
- Fitness Room - Endurance
- Lounge - Charisma
- Game Room - Luck

Comment: Do you have a source for this? It directly contradicts another answer.

Comment: I believe this is so because I had a dweller with high intelligence and he has a child with someone with good intelligence as well. The child they have has a rather low intelligence. It was actually their lowest skill.