# How do I make sure my child is smart?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I am nearing a full vault and I have some dwellers with max stats.

I have noticed that sometimes I get a child with above average stats.

**How do I ensure that my children are borne with higher than normal stats?**

In the following examples the children all the same father and all the mothers have been max stats, 100% happiness and level 50, but they still only one now and then have high stats.

[image: Amanda Rothchild]

[image: Nicholas Murray]

Comment: And another classic Arqade title for the network Hot Questions list...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**These are data taken from Reddit submitted by users and etc.**

- Children have a small chance of being born either rare (28 SPECIAL) or legendary (40 SPECIAL) if the parents' total SPECIAL is high enough.
- SPECIAL-boosting gear does not affect this calculation.
- Children have a 50/50 chance of inheriting the "proficiency" (highest stat) of either parent.
- Maxed parents' proficiency is always Intelligence.
- Child stats appear to be calculated at the time of birth. There is a
  special case to handle "ghost dads" which always results in normal
  children who inherit from the mother, though it is not clear whether
  it's actually used or is just an edge case error handler.

**"Super" Child Formula**

max = (male_total_special + female_total_special - 14) / 126
random_number = random(max / 4, max)
if random_number is greater than 0.95 the child will be legendary
if random_number is greater than 0.85 the child will be rare
otherwise the child will be normal

Notes:

- Parents' total SPECIAL must be 134 or higher to have a chance at a
  legendary child.
- Parents' total SPECIAL must be 122 or higher to have a chance at a
  rare child.
- Two fully maxed out parents (SPECIAL 140) will have a ~6.6% chance of
  producing a legendary child, and a ~13.3% chance of producing a rare
  child.
- Two maxed parents will produce a child with an Intelligence
  proficiency.

**Original link can be found here: [REDDIT SOURCE](https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3jdiao/special_inheritance_and_super_children_vaulttec/)**