# Are there rare children? If so, what conditions are required to birth them?

Tags: fallout-shelter

The [Fallout Wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault_dwellers_%28Fallout_Shelter%29) states that the condition for getting legendary children is to have both parents have maximised stats and level, but it doesn't mention anything about getting "rare" kids (ie., ones starting with a SPECIAL point sum of 28). Are "rare" kids a thing at all? If they are, what are the conditions to spawn them?

Comment: Answered here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/237881/how-do-i-make-sure-my-child-is-smart/237991#237991)

Comment: @Studoku Ah! I was sure I had seen exactly this before, but I wasn't able to locate it again. Yes, it does answer my question exactly. So… What do I do now with the question? I guess it isn't exactly the same as the other question, even if the answers are going to be pretty similar.